# Comparing values within multiple variables

Tags: spss

I have a data set of teachers who are assigned to up to 6 schools in Year 1 and Year 5. I want to see if any of the school codes in Year 1 are the same within the set of school codes for Year 5. Essentially, I am looking to see if teachers changed schools from Year 1 to Year 5, but want to make sure I'm looking across all the school codes, not just the first school listed for each year. Is there a command to compare the values with a set of variables to the values within another set of variables? I imagine vectors and loops might help, but I haven't used them before. In the end, I want to classify teachers are movers (those who moved to a different school in Year 5) and stayers (those who remained at the same school(s) in Year 5 as in Year 1).

The data is structured so that every row is a teacher; there are multiple columns for each school, which are indexed by year (e.g., there are columns for school 1 in 2012, school 2 in 2012, school 1 in 2016, school 2 in 2016 etc.).

Comment: How is your data formatted now? Is every Teacher/School/Year a separate row? Or is it just Teacher/Year on every row? Or just every row is one Teacher?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a few methods to compare multiple variables - basically the `ANY` function, loop commands (`LOOP` and `DO REPEAT`) and restructure commands.

Following are two examples, using school IDs named Yr1School1, Yr1School2 .... Yr5School1, Yr5School2 .... You can of course use your own variable names instead, just make sure they are ordered in the same fashion - if they are not, you'll have to list all the names in the commands instead of using "TO" as in `Yr1School1 TO Yr1School6`.

This example combines a loop with an ANY function:

```
compute SchoolRepeats=0.
do repeat Year1SchoolID=Yr1School1 to Yr1School6.
   if any(Year1SchoolID,Yr5School1 to Yr5School6) SchoolRepeats = SchoolRepeats + 1.
end repeat.
execute.
```

After executing, the variable SchoolRepeats will contain the number of schools which appeared both in year 1 and in year 5.

In this example the file is restructured so that each comparison is in a separate line (every teacher ID has 6X6=36 lines), and now no loop is needed:

```
varstocases/make Year1SchoolID from Yr1School1 to Yr1School6/index=Yr1Index(Year1SchoolID).
varstocases/make Year5SchoolID from Yr5School1 to Yr5School6/index=Yr5Index(Year5SchoolID).
compute SchoolRepeat=(Year1SchoolID = Year5SchoolID).
DATASET DECLARE SumRepeats.
AGGREGATE   /OUTFILE='SumRepeats'   /BREAK=TeacherID /SchoolRepeats=SUM(SchoolRepeat).
```

The new dataset now has the number of repeating shools for each teacher ID.